# Create Table With JDBCTemplate on Runtime

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to create a table on runtime, In my case Columns and datatypes are not fixed so I can't write a constant query, I need to create a table on the basis of column names, with datatypes on runtime. Is there any way that we can create by passing column names and datatypes as an argument via jdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, one must avoid creating table through code, it attracts lots of problems in business logic changes with time. But still, if you are stuck in one kind of situation.
I would suggest write a utility method which create a Sql query of Create Table type by applying business logic and after that you can use any of the two methods:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery);

or

jdbcTemplate.execute(sqlQuery);
```